# Error Linking CUDA 8.0 in VS2015 using OpenCV 3.2

Tags: c++, opencv, cuda

I am having trouble getting Visual Studio to link with CUDA.  In particular, at the end of compiling, I get a series of errors saying that various CUDA functions are not found.  For example:

```
1>gpuImagesClass.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A001289) "extern "C" enum cudaError __cdecl cudaMalloc(void * *,unsigned __int64)" (?cudaMalloc@@$$J0YA?AW4cudaError@@PEAPEAX_K@Z) referenced in function "public: __cdecl gpuImages::gpuImages(int,int)" (??0gpuImages@@$$FQEAA@HH@Z)
1>ChannelClass.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A001732) "extern "C" enum cudaError __cdecl cudaMalloc(void * *,unsigned __int64)" (?cudaMalloc@@$$J0YA?AW4cudaError@@PEAPEAX_K@Z) referenced in function "class cv::Point_<int> __cdecl FindContourPickupGPU(struct CUstream_st * *,class std::vector<class cv::Point_<int>,class std::allocator<class cv::Point_<int> > >)" (?FindContourPickupGPU@@$$FYA?AV?$Point_@H@cv@@PEAPEAUCUstream_st@@V?$vector@V?$Point_@H@cv@@V?$allocator@V?$Point_@H@cv@@@std@@@std@@@Z)
1>gpuImagesClass.obj : error LNK2020: unresolved token (0A0012C2) "extern "C" char const * __cdecl cudaGetErrorString(enum cudaError)" (?cudaGetErrorString@@$$J0YAPEBDW4cudaError@@@Z)
1>ChannelClass.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A00176D) "extern "C" char const * __cdecl cudaGetErrorString(enum cudaError)" (?cudaGetErrorString@@$$J0YAPEBDW4cudaError@@@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl gpuAssert(enum cudaError,char const *,int,bool)" (?gpuAssert@@$$FYAXW4cudaError@@PEBDH_N@Z)
1>ChannelClass.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A001799) "extern "C" enum cudaError __cdecl cudaFree(void *)" (?cudaFree@@$$J0YA?AW4cudaError@@PEAX@Z) referenced in function "class cv::Point_<int> __cdecl FindContourPickupGPU(struct CUstream_st * *,class std::vector<class cv::Point_<int>,class std::allocator<class cv::Point_<int> > >)" (?FindContourPickupGPU@@$$FYA?AV?$Point_@H@cv@@PEAPEAUCUstream_st@@V?$vector@V?$Point_@H@cv@@V?$allocator@V?$Point_@H@cv@@@std@@@std@@@Z)
1>ChannelClass.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A00193F) "extern "C" enum cudaError __cdecl cudaMemcpy(void *,void const *,unsigned __int64,enum cudaMemcpyKind)" (?cudaMemcpy@@$$J0YA?AW4cudaError@@PEAXPEBX_KW4cudaMemcpyKind@@@Z) referenced in function "class cv::Point_<int> __cdecl FindContourPickupGPU(struct CUstream_st * *,class std::vector<class cv::Point_<int>,class std::allocator<class cv::Point_<int> > >)" (?FindContourPickupGPU@@$$FYA?AV?$Point_@H@cv@@PEAPEAUCUstream_st@@V?$vector@V?$Point_@H@cv@@V?$allocator@V?$Point_@H@cv@@@std@@@std@@@Z)
1>gpuImagesClass.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A001388) "extern "C" enum cudaError __cdecl cudaMemGetInfo(unsigned __int64 *,unsigned __int64 *)" (?cudaMemGetInfo@@$$J0YA?AW4cudaError@@PEA_K0@Z) referenced in function "public: __cdecl gpuImages::gpuImages(int,int)" (??0gpuImages@@$$FQEAA@HH@Z)
```

I am hoping for help on what might be set wrong.

I am using VS2015 with OpenCV 3.2, CUDA 8.0 on a Win10 64bit machine.

I downloaded OpenCV 3.2 and built the code using CMake 3.8.1.

That seems to work fine.

I selected CUDA 8.0 in the build customizations for my project and CUDA is appearing in the project properties.

Under Configuration Properties->Debugging->Environment the PATH includes a reference to: "C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\bin"

Under Configuration Properties->VC++ Directories->Include Directories I put the path to the include file of each OpenCV module.

Under Configuration Properties->VC++ Directories->Library Directories I put the path to the directory where each OpenCV module lib file is.

Under Configuration Properties->CUDA C/C++->Common->CUDA Runtime it says "static CUDA runtime library"

The CUDA Linker options are all set to default.

So, I am not sure what needs to be set differently or whether some CUDA related file needs to be moved into a directory.

**EDIT:**  I added cudart.lib to the Configuration Properties->Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies and that cured the linking problem at compile time.

However, as soon as you try and run the app in Debug mode, it crashes with:

```
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFC832F7A7A (ntdll.dll) in SV15.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.
```

This error appears before you get to any of the actual code so I think it must be an incompatability in the various libraries.

Comment: Try adding cuda include path and library path to your project settings. In your case, it would be adding `$(CUDA_PATH)\include` to `Configuration Properties->VC++ Directories->Include Directories` and adding `$(CUDA_PATH)\lib\x64` to `Configuration Properties->VC++ Directories->Library Directories`.

Comment: I did that and got no change.  There is an environment variable labeled CUDA_PATH that points to C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0 so that would seem to be correct.

Comment: Does your `Configuration Properties -> Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories` contain `$(CUDA_PATH)\lib\x64`? If not, you can try adding it. I've faced similar issue before and this fixed the linker issue.

Comment: I put that reference there and there was no effect.  I also put that reference in Configuration Properties->CUDA Linker->Additional Library Directories and again there was no effect.

Comment: Last thing I can think of is that `cudart.lib` should be configured to be linked. If `Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies` doesn't contain `cudart.lib` in the list, you should add it.

Comment: Well, that solved the linking error.  I am now getting an immediate run time error claiming an access violation but it is not clear that the linking error and the runtime error are related.

Comment: You can edit the post and  share the exact error message.

Comment: Did that.  Thanks

Comment: Maybe x86/x64 issue. If you are building in x86, you can try x64 build. Also, I think adding `bin` path to `Configuration Properties->Debugging->Environment` might be redundant thing to do becuase your system's `Path` environment variable should already contain the `bin` path if you install CUDA in Windows. (It did for my case)